# MS Access: Find the most common user per month query

Tags: database, ms-access-2016

Fairly new to Access 2016 and I'm writing a query to obtain the most common user within the database per month.

So a record would be

```
Table1
ID    Date1    
1     2019-02-28
```

This is my code grouping the totals per month:

```
Month: Format([Date1],"mmmm")
TopUser: (SELECT TOP 1 [Table1]![ID] FROM [Table1] GROUP BY     
[Table1]![ID] order by COUNT([Table1]![ID]) DESC)
```

Expectation:

```
Month     TopUser
January   2
February  1
March     2
April     3
```

Result:

```
Month     TopUser
January   2
February  2
March     2
April     2
```

So my code is returning back the most common user overall instead of for each month. I'm not sure if this is an access aspect that I'm misinterpreting or if its my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering on the month:

```
Select 
    Format([Date1], "yyyymm") As YearMonth,
        (Select Top 1 T.ID 
        From Table1 As T
        Where Format(T.[Date1], "yyyymm") = Format(Table1.[Date1], "yyyymm")
        Group By ID
        Order By Count(T.ID) Desc) As TopID
From
    Table1
Group By
    Format([Date1], "yyyymm")
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the message "Your query does not include the specified expression 'T![ID]' as part of an aggregate function".

Comment: Yes, true. Try the edited answer with the revised full query.